# Advanced Element Queries - example uses

Tags: elementquery

In Craft docs [element queries article](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries), there is section "advanced element queries", with methods like `where`, `groupBy` etc.

What are example use cases of these methods in Twig templates or PHP modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simply low level operations you can do to more specifically filter the elements that should be returned. It is generally more common to use them in plugins/modules than in Twig templates, but the use-cases are numerous. A few trivial examples are below.

```
{{ set entries = craft.entries.where(['authorId', 1]).all() }}

{{ set entries = craft.entries.where(['in', 'authorId', [1, 2, 3]]).all() }}

{{ set entries = craft.entries.where(['>=', 'dateCreated', '2021-01-01']).all() }}

{{ set entries = craft.entries.where(['like', 'title', 'prefix%']).all() }}
```

Detailed docs for `where` and other DB query parameters can be found here:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#where